# What UI Framework is Instagram using?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I am interested to find out what UI Framework Instagram is using. Was wondering if anyone can enlighten me on that.

Any advise on this will be greatly appreciated!

Zhen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same UI framework as most iOS apps, Cocoa Touch. They've just customized many of the controls. Here's some information on how to do similar customization:

- [**The UITabBar with the center bump**](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/)
- [**The custom UITabBar notifications**](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/03/08/how-does-the-instagram-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar-notification/)
- [**The custom UINavigationBar**](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/)
- The scrolling picture list is similar to [**SSToolkit's**](http://sstoolk.it/) [**SSCollectionView**](http://sstoolk.it/documentation/Classes/SSCollectionView)

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the response. I was actually thinking of using iUi Framework (Three20) to build an application that draws most of its content from facebook. Can I check if you know it is better to use Cocoa touch or iUi Framework for such applications?

Comment: @Zhen Ah, you're talking about Javascript/web frameworks? I assumed you were talking about Objective-C frameworks, which is what Instagram and most native apps are written in -- you definitely can't write InstaGram with a web framework. I know nothing about iUi other than what I just read, and Three20 has nothing to do with it other than having been written by the same person. The only overlap I see between Instagram and Three20 is the imageViewer, which could be helpful, but it's still Objective-C, not a web framework.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I think I was confused... I was indeed talking about Objective C frameworks only. I always thought that Three20 and iUi are the same thing? Just to confirm, am I right to say that iUi has nothing to do with iPhone dev, it's just a framework to allow developers to develop web apps to look like iphone apps? Probably Three20 is the one I am interested in which I presume is the one I can use to build my iPhone app?

Comment: @Zhen You're correct that iUi has nothing to do with Three20 other than being written by the same person (Joe Hewitt), and that iUi is a web framework that can make mobile apps look and feel more like native iPhone apps than some other such javascript libraries. Three20 has some good features, but isn't really a full framework for building your entire app, it just makes certain things easier, like the tutorials and libraries I pointed you to in my answer. Three20 is simply customized Cocoa Touch, and you can use only the pieces that suit you.

Comment: I wonder if it's actually SSCollectionView. That would be awesome :)