# Hide navbar & tabs when scrolling down like Instagram

Tags: onsen-ui

How would you do to hide the navigation bar and tabs when the user scroll down like Instagram app?

Comment: I believe this addresses what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6106329/400552

Comment: See https://community.onsen.io/topic/615/hide-bars-tab-bar-and-toolbar-on-scroll/4 and https://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/VjgBqQ